# Does 2 Samuel 12:9-11 prove that God will sometimes never stop His chastisements upon a Christian?

Tags: sin, judgement, curses

We read that after King David sinned against God, Uriah, Bathsheba, and the whole nation of Israel; God said “the sword shall never depart from your house”.  **Q: Can we find any exegetical grounds with 2 Samuel 12:10 to assume that God may in fact never let a temporal judgment off of any of His people for their sins in this life?**

“Why have you despised the commandment of the Lord, to do evil in His sight? You have killed Uriah the Hittite with the sword; you have taken his wife to be your wife, and have killed him with the sword of the people of Ammon.

***Now therefore, the sword shall never depart from your house***, because you have despised Me, and have taken the wife of Uriah the Hittite to be your wife.’

Thus says the Lord: ‘Behold, I will raise up adversity against you from your own house; and I will take your wives before your eyes and give them to your neighbor, and he shall lie with your wives in the sight of this sun.”
‭‭II Samuel‬ ‭12:9-11‬

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is, "yes" as 2 Sam 12 shows.  However, the same idea of God allowing circumstances to chasten us (at times) is explicitly taught in the NT:

- Rev 3:19 - Those whom I love I rebuke and discipline. So be earnest and repent.
- Heb 12:5 - And have you completely forgotten this word of encouragement that addresses you as a father addresses his son? It says, “My son, do not make light of the Lord’s discipline, and do not lose heart when he rebukes you,
- Heb 12:6 - because the Lord disciplines the one he loves, and he chastens everyone he accepts as his son.”
- Heb 12:11 - No discipline seems pleasant at the time, but painful. Later on, however, it produces a harvest of righteousness and peace for those who have been trained by it.
- 1 Cor 11:32 - Nevertheless, when we are judged in this way by the Lord, we are being disciplined so that we will not be finally condemned with the world.

... and so forth.  God must often allow circumstances to chasten us to better focus our minds on what is important.

Comment: Great answer.  I’ve studied these New Testament passages before.  & as your answer said “yes”, my mind wonders how long certain judgments can last upon any one believer.  I noticed you have also said “at times” with respect to the chastening of God.

Comment: @Cork88 - It is true that God chastens us.  At the same times, we often bring troubles on ourselves as well buy a very stupid decisions, or at other times by the silly choices of others.  "In this life you will have trouble" say Jesus in John 16:33.